# How can I add an extra integral template argument to my class?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm making a function container like std::function, and the following is what I have, but I would like to have an additional integer parameter to decide the size of a small buffer optimisation. What way would be a good way to do it?

```
template <typename T>
class MyDynamicCallable{ };

template <typename ret_t, typename ... arg_types>
class MyDynamicCallable<ret_t(arg_types...)>
{public:
    template <typename callable_t>
    MyDynamicCallable(callable_t&& callable)
    {
        obj_ptr = MemMngr::mem_alloc(sizeof(callable));
        
        new (obj_ptr) callable_t(std::forward<callable_t>(callable));
        call_func_ptr = &call_object<callable_t>;
    }
    




    ret_t (*call_func_ptr)(void*, arg_types...) = nullptr;
    void* obj_ptr = nullptr;

private:
    template <typename callable_t>
    static ret_t call_object(void* obj, arg_types ... args)
    {
        return (*(callable_t*)obj)(std::forward<arg_types>(args)...);
    }
public:

    void reset() {
        call_func_ptr = nullptr;

    }
    ret_t operator()(arg_types ... args) const { return call_func_ptr(obj_ptr, std::forward<arg_types>(args) ...);  }
    //void operator=(MyDynamicCallable&&) = delete;
    //void operator=(const MyDynamicCallable&) = delete;



};
```

Comment: *"good way to do it?..."* Opinion based and unclear.

Comment: It's trivial but why not just add a non-type template parameter of type `std::size_t`?

Answer (score 3):

You could add it as the first template parameter:

```cpp
template <std::size_t N, typename T>
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
class MyDynamicCallable /* {} */; // removed implementation

template <std::size_t N, typename ret_t, typename... arg_types>
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
class MyDynamicCallable<N, ret_t(arg_types...)> {
//                      ^
```

or last if you want to be able to make it have a default value:

```cpp
template <typename T, std::size_t N = 4> // N is here 4 by default
class MyDynamicCallable;

template <typename ret_t, typename... arg_types, std::size_t N>
class MyDynamicCallable<ret_t(arg_types...), N> {
```

Comment: @Zebrafish I realize I didn't follow up in a couple of hours, but, yes as both answers have shown. Is there anything we should fill or have we answered your question?

Answer (score 1):

It's trivial but you could add a non-type template parameter of type `std::size_t` as shown below:

```
template <std::size_t N, typename T>
class MyDynamicCallable{ };

template <std::size_t N, typename ret_t, typename ... arg_types>
class MyDynamicCallable<N, ret_t(arg_types...)>
{
    //other code as before
}
```

---

> Can it be defaulted?

Yes

```
template < typename T, std::size_t N = 10>
class MyDynamicCallable{ }; 

template <std::size_t N, typename ret_t, typename ... arg_types>
class MyDynamicCallable< ret_t(arg_types...), N>
{
    //other code as before
};
```